# BBCode vs. wiki markup for collaboration software

Tags: content-management-system, wiki, markup, collaboration, bbcode

I'm developing a web application to facilitate the playing of pen-and-paper RPGs over the internet.  I'm trying to determine whether BBCode or some flavor of wiki markup is preferable. BBCode and tikiwiki markup both have packages in the PHP::PEAR repository and I admit a preference for tikiwiki, but I haven't been able to figure out much in the way of qualitative differences between options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *need* markup?  Is there some reason a WYSIWYG editor wouldn't do the job?  See eg. the FCKEditor extension for MediaWiki:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FCKeditor_(Official)

Comment: Let me answer that with a definitive nnnnyeeeeeeesssss.  Which is to say, I hadn't really thought of that - I'm a pretty web 1.0 guy, and even though my project is awash with AJAX and whatnot I guess my judgment lapsed.  FCKeditor or similar it is.